# Nestjs request scope data during authentication

Tags: nestjs

What is an equivalent to res.locals from express in nest.js?
In other words what are the ways I can pass data about user between middlewares and to the controller?

Comment: Have you tried looking into nest.js [Middlewares](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware) and [Controllers](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers)? The response object can be provided to both and can also be manipulated the same way it would be in a native express app.

Comment: I did, buy if I use response object I can no longer make use of interceptors.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the nestjs it is common to assigned that data to the request because as you said using response directly will break the pipeline of interceptors and middlewares.

From controllers page: 
[image]
From interceptors page:
[image]